# Animate (easeOutCirc) a DOM Element using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, jquery-animate, angularjs-animation

How can I write this piece of the code in AnguarJs ?

Particularly the animation part (`easeOutCirc`) used in this example:

`$(document).ready(function () {
    function addCircle() {
        var $circle = $('<div class="circle"></div>');
        $circle.animate({
            'width': '300px',
            'height': '300px',
            'margin-top': '-150px',
            'margin-left': '-150px',
            'opacity': '0'
        }, 4000, 'easeOutCirc');
        $('body').append($circle);
        setTimeout(function __remove() {
            $circle.remove();
        }, 4000);
    }
    addCircle();
    setInterval(addCircle, 1200);
});`

http://jsfiddle.net/Y3r36/311/

Comment: angualr ships with jqlite...https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

Comment: Use `jsfiddle` or `jsbin` what is working!!!

Comment: I added a jsFiddle link :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use something like this? 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate